# Why does adding one smallint column to result slow query by factor of 60?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I have what seems to me to be a routine table and a table creation script that I have put in /tmp/try.sql.  I am running postgres under OSX 10.10.2.

Here is the table:

```
cow_dev=# \d carc
                                Table "public.carc"
    Column     |     Type     |                         Modifiers
---------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------   ---------
 internal_id   | integer      | not null default nextval('carc_internal_id_seq'::regclass)
 acct_nbr      | character(6) |
 birth_date    | date         |
 anm_key       | integer      |
 slghtr_dt     | date         |
 sire_assoc_id | integer      |
 sire_reg      | text         |
 dam_assoc_id  | integer      |
 dam_reg       | text         |
 sex           | text         |
 carc_kphf_pct | real         |
 carc_wt       | integer      |
 marbling      | integer      |
 ribeye_area   | real         |
 usda_qlty_grd | smallint     |
 act_fat_thick | real         |
 carcass_group | text         |
 maturity      | integer      |
Indexes:
    "idx_a649568319866892fcdd3742289e8294" PRIMARY KEY, btree (internal_id)
    "idx_d4659e9f750ff68c75e11e89a950e386" btree (anm_key)
    "idx_d57025002b9ce54cf590b76e87c10cac" btree (acct_nbr)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "carc_acct_nbr__acct_acct_nbr_fk" FOREIGN KEY (acct_nbr) REFERENCES acct(acct_nbr)
    "carc_anm_key__anm_anm_key_fk" FOREIGN KEY (anm_key) REFERENCES anm(anm_key)
```

Here is the script:

```
create temp table carc_out as
     with assoc_map as 
     (select
         a.assoc_id,
         c.code_3 || a.brd_cd_id mb_name
      from
         assoc a
         join country_code c on c.code_2 = a.country_code_2)
     select
        c.internal_id,
        n.mb_assoc_reg anm_nbr,
        c.act_fat_thick,
        c.carc_kphf_pct,
        c.carcass_group,
        c.carc_wt,
        null::float carc_yld,
        c.marbling,
        c.maturity,
        c.ribeye_area,
        to_char(c.slghtr_dt, 'mmddyyyy') slghtr_dt,
        c.usda_qlty_grd
from
        carc c
        left join z2_raa_numbers n using (anm_key)
        left join assoc_map da on da.assoc_id = coalesce(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) 
        left join assoc_map sa on sa.assoc_id = coalesce(c.sire_assoc_id, 1);
drop table carc_out;
```

Here are the results of running it twice, the first with the c.usda_qlty_grd not included in the query and the second with it included.

```
> time psql -U cow_peer -d cow_dev -c '\i /tmp/try.sql'
SELECT 25332
DROP TABLE

real    0m3.041s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
10:57:46 521 0 tom@angus-2 ~
> time psql -U cow_peer -d cow_dev -c '\i /tmp/try.sql'
SELECT 25332
DROP TABLE

real    3m1.958s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
```

As you can see, it takes 3 seconds one time and 3 minutes the other.  This is repeatable and is at least somewhat independent of what additional column you add to the query.  Interestingly the user and sys times don't seem to change.  I am perplexed.

Any claims I made that the execution plans were identical were in error.  There are, however, quite similar.

This is without the additional column:

```
                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=1220.51..122913.55 rows=25332 width=54)
   Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.sire_assoc_id, 1) = sa.assoc_id)
   CTE assoc_map
 ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.54..10.16 rows=52 width=11)
       Hash Cond: (a.country_code_2 = c_1.code_2)
           ->  Seq Scan on assoc a  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=10)
           ->  Hash  (cost=4.46..4.46 rows=246 width=7)
                 ->  Seq Scan on country_code c_1  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=246 width=7)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1208.66..122614.19 rows=25332 width=58)
         Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) = da.assoc_id)
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1206.97..122451.64 rows=25332 width=62)
               Hash Cond: (n.anm_key = c.anm_key)
              ->  Seq Scan on z2_raa_numbers n  (cost=0.00..61034.69 rows=3330869 width=19)
               ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=51)
                 ->  Seq Scan on carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=51)
     ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
           ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map da  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
         ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map sa  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
```

This one contains the additional column:

```
                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=1220.51..122913.55 rows=25332 width=56)
   Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.sire_assoc_id, 1) = sa.assoc_id)
   CTE assoc_map
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.54..10.16 rows=52 width=11)
           Hash Cond: (a.country_code_2 = c_1.code_2)
           ->  Seq Scan on assoc a  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=10)
           ->  Hash  (cost=4.46..4.46 rows=246 width=7)
                 ->  Seq Scan on country_code c_1  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=246 width=7)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1208.66..122614.19 rows=25332 width=60)
         Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) = da.assoc_id)
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1206.97..122451.64 rows=25332 width=64)
               Hash Cond: (n.anm_key = c.anm_key)
               ->  Seq Scan on z2_raa_numbers n  (cost=0.00..61034.69 rows=3330869 width=19)
               ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=53)
                     ->  Seq Scan on carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=53)
      ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
               ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map da  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
         ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map sa  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4)
```

Perhaps I should note that I did reboot, just in case.

Comment: Maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask.

Comment: Edit your question and add the execution plans `explain (analyze, verbose)` of both queries (formatted text please no screenshots)

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that the execution plans were identical.  I can add it if you think that would be useful.

Comment: you are LEFT JOINING twice (da,sa) to the CTE `assoc_map`, but I do not see any of its columns referenced. Makes little sense to me.

Comment: @user3416742 The execution plans surely were not identical if one has an extra column. Also, don't run it twice. Run each of the queries several time until the time of the execution doesn't vary much.

Comment: When I said it was repeatable what I mean was that I had run it several times until the execution times don't vary much.The left joins are there because there were additional columns in the query and I took them out until it suddenly got fast.

Comment: `The left joins are there because there were additional columns in the query and I took them out until it suddenly got fast.` Please post the real query. You are wasting people's time.